# in sql how to select rows from table if some flag is ON or off in other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

i have two table

table 1

```
**Menuname    MenuCode** 
  Dept        Dept
  Sub Dept    SubDept
  Group       Group
  Tag         Tag 
  Item        Item
  Tender      Tender
  Register    Register
```

table 2

```
Id   IsDept  IsSubDept  IsGroup  IsTag
1    1       0          1        0
```

There is not any connection between this two table. 4 flags are set in Table2 for first four rows from Table1.

i want to select only rows from Table1 which flag is true from Table2. and remaining all

if IsDept is true then want to select first row of Table1 with MenuName  Dept. 
and others which flags is not defined.

Expected Result

```
**Menuname    MenuCode** 
      Dept        Dept
      Group       Group
      Item        Item
      Tender      Tender
      Register    Register
```

how to query this.??

Comment: If the tables does not have a relationship, then it is not possible. I mean, is not possible in a way that makes sense, at least.

Comment: ya i know but i have to do this for only 4 rows. i have many rows in Table1. so if we can use any Case statement or whatever?

Comment: Table2 contains only a single row?

Comment: Yes its fix. only single row with fix columns

Comment: SO there is no relation between the tables? nothing to join on, etc...  how many rows are in table 2? Are you selecting via id from it, and want to get the descriptions from table1? the schema is  bit confusing, so not sure what the end result would look like, can you post expected results? and would it be possible to adjust your schema or are you "stuck" with it.

Comment: There are many rows in Table1. in Table2 its only single row with this four static columns. i have to select all rows from Table1. but for that 4 Rows i have to check in Table2. its static. i can do this by If condition in my front end. but if there is any query in sql so it will be good.

Answer (score 1):

Since table2 have only one row, you can do a crossjoin and a simple WHERE will give the result you want:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where isdept = 1 and menuname like 'Dept%';
```

Comment: by this query i will not able to select other rows from table1. there are many more columns in Table1 and have to select that all time. but only this 4 column i have to use conditions.

Comment: You just need to use different conditions to select other rows. I just have used the example that you ask on your question.

Comment: @Zohar, the question was: "if IsDept is true then want to select first row of Table1 with MenuName Dept. how to query this.??" No group row was mentioned...

Comment: *i want to select only rows from Table1 which flag is true from Table2.* `Dept` was an example, the `IsGroup` was also flagged as true.

Comment: Then, it is needed only to extend the logic to any other flags... I present a query illustrating what to do for dept.

Answer (score 1):

Might be able to brute force it, and combine the results via a union?

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t2.isdept = 1 AND t1.menucode='dept'
UNION
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t2.issubdept = 1 and t1.menucode='subdept'
UNION
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t2.isgroup = 1 and t1.menucode='group'
UNION
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t2.istag = 1 and t1.menucode='tag';
```

but will probably need to then uniq the result as well

Answer (score 0):

Walter provided a good solution for picking the `Dept` if `isDept` is marked, this is an extension of his solution that extends that logic to the other flags:

```
SELECT MenuCode, MenuName
FROM @Table1 
CROSS JOIN @Table2 
WHERE 
     (
       (IsDept = 1 AND MenuCode = 'Dept')
       OR (IsSubDept = 1 AND MenuCode = 'SubDept')
       OR (IsGroup = 1 AND MenuCode = 'Group')
       OR (IsTag = 1 AND MenuCode = 'Tag')
     )
OR MenuCode NOT IN('Dept', 'SubDept', Group', 'Tag')
```

My initial solution was using bitwise operations but it's more complicated:

```
DECLARE @Flags int

SELECT  @Flags = IsDept * 8 + 
                 IsSubDept * 4 +
                 IsGroup * 2 +
                 IsTag 
FROM Table2 

SELECT MenuCode, MenuName
FROM Table1 
WHERE (
        (MenuCode = 'Dept' AND @Flags & 8 = 8)
        OR (MenuCode = 'SubDept' AND @Flags & 4 = 4)
        OR (MenuCode = 'Group' AND @Flags & 2 = 2)
        OR (MenuCode = 'Tag' AND @Flags & 1 = 1)
      )
OR MenuCode NOT IN('Dept', 'SubDept', Group', 'Tag')
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for your reply, with your query it selects rows from Table1 which flag is true from Table2. its goog but along this i want all others rows which flags are not defined. i mean there are 50 rows in Table 1. remaining 46 rows i need to select everytime. but for this 4 rows only i have to check flag from Table2. with your query i am able to select only this 4 rows. hope i am explaining well so you can understand. Thanks.